# Changing Previous Commits SourceTree

Tags: git, commit, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree, git-checkout

Again, I'm new to Git so this might seem like a stupid question. I have a master branch with 7 commits. I want to go back to the 3rd commit because I realized that it is there where everything has stopped working. I assume I should check out the 3rd commit. However, when I do this my working copy becomes a detached head. My new commits don't go on the master branch like they normally would. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options you have here:

1. If you already pushed and you don't care to rewrite history on the remote you can do:

   `$ git reset --hard <commitID-of-third-commit>`

and push the stuff.

2. If you have not pushed the commits yet, you can do the same as in 1. but without the trouble of rewriting history on remote

**Keep in mind, `git reset --hard` is destructive and will destroy uncommited as well as already commited changes**

3. If you don't want to rewrite history on remote you have to revert all the commits between the 3rd and the last one and move on from there.

   `$ git revert <commit 4>`

   `$ git revert <commit 5>`

etc.

Comment: Be aware that using `$ git reset --hard` is potentially **destructive**, since you loose all uncommited changes.

Comment: Thx i will add this, I thought this would be clear, but it's always better to say it.

Answer (score 1):

If you checkout a commit via `$ git checkout <commit id>`, you end up with a detached head, as you said. If you want to continue working from this point, you have to create a new branch using `$ git checkout -b <new_branch_name>`.

If you want to reset your current branch to an older commit, you can use `$ git reset`, as stated in [ckruczeks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42525916/7598462). But be aware that a (hard) reset is potentially destructive, since you loose uncommited changes and some of your commits are no longer accesible via your branch. If you're not entirely sure you do not need those commits any more, you can checkout a backup branch before the `$ git reset` call.

It's generally not advisable to hard reset a branch that you already pushed to a remote. Other people could already be working on top of the branch you are about to reset.